# Tcl - Accessing Fields from a C Struct

Tags: c, tcl, orcad

I'm trying to do some automation in OrCAD Capture using its Tcl scripting interface. I've run into a problem of receiving a struct, but not having any exposed functions to deal with it. I know the structure of the struct (it's a [LOGFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) so is there anyway to unpack the struct?

I've found [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) that allows creating Tcl interfaces to C libraries. I'd really rather not have to ship C code just to access a simple struct though!

Comment: How do you receive the struct? As binary data or as pointer to some memory location?

Comment: I think it might be a pointer? I get something along the lines of _60e6d70d_p_LOGFONT when I puts the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is really the kind of thing you need to be asking your product vendor about. Searching doesn't turn up much useful information, although several posts on Cadence forums seem to indicate that the documentation you need is in a file named "`OrCAD_Capture_TclTk_Extensions.pdf`", (look in *instdir*/tools/capture/tclscripts/). Also, `_60e6d70d_p_LOGFONT` is an object handle. It looks like it's a command... So, `set $logfont [command_that_returns_this_handle]`, and then `$logfont` will be the command to invoke object methods, which should be documented in "`OrCAD_Capture_TclTk_Extensions.pdf`".

<sub>This was the sense that I extracted from http://www.cadence.com/Community/forums/p/15614/1294051.aspx. See for yourself.</sub>

Comment: I've been working extensively from OrCAD_Capture_TclTk_Extensions.pdf, I can get a handle to a LOGFONT from a DboCommentText object, but I haven't found any functions to retrieve information from within the LOGFONT object. (Facename, styles, orientation, etc.) Since it's just a struct, and I know the offsets of all of the fields, I'm wondering if there's any native Tcl method of accessing the data.

Comment: If the handle isn't a command, (what happens if you try to treat it as one?),
I don't believe you can do it in pure Tcl. I'm
not aware of any pure-tcl method for getting the content of arbitrary memory
locations. However, the twapi extension might have an answer, as it provides
tcl command wrappings for the win32 API.